# How to point Hudson build to my local git repository?

Tags: git, github, hudson

Currently, my Hudson build is set up to pull code from GitHub. In the Hudson build config, under "Source Control Management" -> "Repository URL" I have something like:

```
git@github.com:{companyname}/{reponame}.git
```

Is there any way (and what is the syntax) to point that build to my local repository, that is on my box?

Comment: Are you asking how to populate a newly created repository on GitHub with the contents of a local git repository?

Comment: Is your repository available to the machine where the Jenkins worker is executed. (i.e.: if the jenkins worker and the repo are not in the same machine, is the repo accessible through SMB, ssh, http or any other means?)

Comment: @cforbish no, I want to know how to point Hudson to build against working directory on my machine

Comment: @pgilmon yes, it is, but good point to check....

Comment: @IamReck no yet, I might have some networking issues that I am debugging, as I get ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your workers have access to the local file it would look like this -

```
file:///path/to/file/repo/project.git
```

Just using the `file://` prefix will get you there.